# Why not use a snooker cue on a standard pool table?

Tags: equipment, snooker

What are the benefits or drawbacks of using a snooker cue rather than a standard cue on a regular pool table?

Comment: You could improve this question by specifying what type of pool you are referring to.

Comment: Generally, American 8-ball on a 9-foot table. 30 years ago in my 40s I used a nice little 2-piece snooker cue on bar tables [8-ball] and out-shot most everyone. That cue was lost years ago. Now [nearing 80] I'm trying to regain my game at the senior center and having terrible luck with a 13mm tipped cue. I'm trying to figure out if I should gamble on the expence of a new or used snooker cue. Oh, and my left eye has distortion in it now. So, there's that too. Thanks for the info so far. It's been helpful. :) pip

Answer (score 3):

There's a few differences between a snooker cue and a pool one:

**Weight:** Because pool balls are heavier than their snooker cousins pool cues tend to be heavier to match. The weight distribution is also different - pool cues are heavier on the grip where snooker cues have more weight at the tip.

**Tip size:** Snooker cues have a narrower tip (~9-10mm vs 12-13mm)

So what do these differences mean? Snooker cues are optimized for *accuracy* rather than power or cue-ball control as pool cues are. This is the case because of various factors - snooker balls are smaller, the pockets are rounded (i.e. you have to be more accurate to pot then in pool), the table is *significantly* bigger which further increases the need for accuracy.

So to answer your question if you were to use a snooker cue on a regular pool table you'd benefit from potting accuracy but lose out on the ability to hit harder and to position the cue ball were you wanted. Additionally while the tip is only slightly smaller the difference in ball sizing means that using a snooker cue to hit pool balls increases your chances of miscuing and imparting unwanted spin on the cue ball (and ultimately object ball as well).

Comment: Here in the UK pool balls are actually smaller and lighter, and using a snooker cue makes far more sense than a pool cue.

Comment: @AndyP True.. I must confess I had presumed from the way the OP had worded the question that they were talking about an American style pool table.

Comment: I agree with @AndyP - I play with a snooker cue on UK tournament tables and you can easily position the cue ball wherever you wish with side, top and bottom applied.